# Getting rid of basepoints

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory

Let $A\subset X$ be a pair of path connected spaces and $x\in A$ a fixed point. For $n\geq1$, let $\pi_1(A,x)$ act on $\pi_n(X,A,x)$ as follows: Given a class $[f]$ and path $[\omega]\in \pi_1(A,x)$, we define $[f]\cdot[\omega]$ as the class of the map $(D^n,S^{n-1},*)\rightarrow (X,A,x)$ $$D^n\xrightarrow{\text{pinch map}}D^n\vee D^n\xrightarrow{1\vee \pi_1}D^n\vee I\xrightarrow{f\vee\omega}X$$(where $*=(0,\cdots,0,1)$ and $\pi_1$ is the projection onto the first coordinate). Let $\pi_n(X,A,*)^\dagger$ be the quotient of $\pi_n(X,A,x)$ modulo the normal subgroup generated by elements $([\omega]\cdot[f])*[f]^{-1}$, for $[\omega]\in\pi_1(A,x)$ and $[f]\in\pi_n(X,A,x)$.

Next, define $\pi_n(X,A)^\sharp$ be the group obtained by taking the free groups generated by maps $(D^n,S^{n-1})\rightarrow(X,A)$ quotient by the subgroup generated by the following set of elements:

1. $f-g$, for all $f,g$ which are pair homotopic
2. $f+g-f*g$, for all $f,g$ such that $f*g$ is defined, where $*$ is the concatenation defined as $$D^n\xrightarrow{\text{pinch map}}D^n\vee D^n\xrightarrow{f\vee g}X$$

Now, I want to prove the following theorem

> The composition $$[(D^n,S^{n-1},*),(X,A,x)]\xrightarrow{\text{forget point}}[(D^n,S^{n-1}),(X,A)]\xrightarrow{\text{quotient}}\pi_n(X,A)^\sharp$$ factors through an isomorphism $F:\pi_n(X,A,x)^\dagger\xrightarrow\sim\pi_n(X,A)^\sharp$.

We do so by constructing the inverse of $F$: For every $y\in A$ select a path $\omega_y$ from $y$ to $x$ (we take $\omega_x=\text{const}_x$). Take $f:(D^n,S^{n-1})\rightarrow (X,A)$, with $y=f(*)$, and map to into the class $Q(f):=[\omega_y*f]\in\pi_n(X,A,x)^\dagger$ of the concatenation $\omega_y*f$. Then we show that this map lift to a map $\pi_n(X,A)^\sharp\rightarrow\pi_n(X,A,x)^\dagger$ by showing that the elements in the form 1. and 2. are mapped to zero.

First, let $f,g$ be pair homotopic, $H:D^n\times I\rightarrow X$ be such homotopy and $\chi:H(*,-):I\rightarrow A$, then let $y=f(*),z=g(*)$  $$Q(f)=[\omega_y*f]=[\omega_z*\chi*\omega^{-1}_y]*[\omega_y*f]=[\omega_z*\chi*\omega^{-1}_y*\omega_y*f]=[\omega_z*\chi*f]=[\omega_z*g]=Q(g)$$(We define $K:\chi*f\rightarrow g$ by setting $K(-,t)$ equal the concatenation of $\omega|_{[t,1]}$ and $H(-,t)$).

Then let $f,g$ be such that $y=f(*)=g(*)$, then $Q(f)+Q(g)=[\omega_y*f]*[\omega_y*g]$ and $Q(f*g)=[\omega_y*(f*g)]$. Then

1. $[\omega_y*f]*[\omega_y*g]$ are two disks $D^n$ (corresponding to $f,g$) touching at $y$ with two copies of $\omega_y$ attached from $y$ to $x$.
2. $[\omega_y*(f*g)]$ is equal to a disck $D^n$ (corresponding to $f*g$) with a single path $\omega_y$ attached.

These two maps in $X$ are the same map but with two different "parametrizations". So $Q(f)+Q(g)-Q(f*g)=0$ and thus $Q$ factors through a map $$P:\pi_n(X,A)^\sharp\rightarrow \pi_n(X,A,x)^\dagger$$

Does this construction/argument make sense? I used that $A$ is path-connected, but not $X$, so I conclude that $X$ need not be path-connected, is this correct?.